# How to submit the form using Symfony 2 Web test case Functional testing

Tags: symfony, phpunit

What i have done is following this tutorial 
http://www.ens.ro/2012/06/22/symfony2-jobeet-day-11-testing-your-forms/

Not able to get the click events for submitting the Form

**Update after comment :**

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET','/dashboard');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('save and continue')->form();
```

// case sensitive for the input e.g. `value="save and continue"`

In my dashboard page , there is form called `form_stepone` , I need to submit that

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET','/dashboard');
```

in this link what must be the URL its a action of the form or page link where form is present

Comment: You should post what you've done because I followed this link, and you're the only one with it don't work... And... I don't like to follow link, it's better for helpers to see YOUR code.

Comment: Yes right posting my code here ,
 $client = static::createClient();
  
  $crawler = $client->request('GET','/dashboard');
  
  $form = $crawler->selectButton('save and continue')->form(); // case sensitive for the input e.g. value="save and continue"
  
  
  
  
  
  In my dashboard page , there is form called form_stepone , i need to submit that
   $crawler = $client->request('GET','/dashboard'); in this link what must be the URL
   its a action of the form or page link where form is present